# Differentiate two JSON keys in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I have this code which has two identical keys with the same name 'title'. However, I don't know how to assign them to the variables in Flutter because when I put 'title' Flutter goes to the API and doesn't understand which title from those two I'm talking about. Do you know how I can solve this to make it get the title from one film to title1 and the second film to title2?

**Flutter code (conection part):**

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:proyecto_brian
/modelos/objeto.dart';

Future<MostPopular> obtenerInfo() async {
  final respuesta = await Dio().get(
      'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=0e685fd77fb3d76874a3ac26e0db8a4b&language=en-US&page=1');

  final Map<String, dynamic> json = respuesta.data;

  final MostPopular mostpopular = MostPopular.fromJson(json);

  return mostpopular;
}
```

**Object part:**

**The JSON code with the titles:**

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "adult": false,
            "backdrop_path": "/fPGeS6jgdLovQAKunNHX8l0avCy.jpg",
            "genre_ids": [
                28,
                12,
                53,
                10752
            ],
            "id": 567189,
            "popularity": 4006.705,
            "poster_path": "/rEm96ib0sPiZBADNKBHKBv5bve9.jpg",
            "release_date": "2021-04-29",
            **"title"**: "Tom Clancy's Without Remorse",
        },
        {
            "adult": false,
            "backdrop_path": "/6ELCZlTA5lGUops70hKdB83WJxH.jpg",
            "genre_ids": [
                28,
                14,
                12
            ],
            "id": 460465,
            "popularity": 3477.711,
            "poster_path": "/nkayOAUBUu4mMvyNf9iHSUiPjF1.jpg",
            "release_date": "2021-04-07",
            **"title"**: "Mortal Kombat",
        },
}
```

Comment: `(json["results"] as List).map((j) => j["title"])`

Comment: it still shows error: final String title = json[(json["results"] as List).map((j) => j["overview"])]; i think it can make a difference between the first title (tom clancy's...) and the second one (mortal kombat) and that where i get confused, i don't know how to make it different, maybe do you know another solution? thank you!!

Comment: Since there's more than one title, you should use `List<String>` instead of `String`, so it'll be `final List<String> titles = (json["results"] as List).map((j) => j["title"]).toList();`.

Comment: so the code will end like this, right? class MostPopular {
  MostPopular({this.title1,});
  final String title1;
  

  factory MostPopular.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final List<String> title = json[(json["results"] as List).map((j) => j["title"]).toList()];
    return MostPopular(title1: title);
  }
}
 at the end, it shows this error: The argument type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. do you know how to solve it? i'm just a bigginer with flutter.

Comment: Let's start from the beginning: what are you trying to with this JSON? Actually as I understand it, you want to choose a single value from it, but what's your criteria? From these two movies, "Tom Clancy's Without Remorse" and "Mortal Kombat", what one should be returned and why? Can it be the first one? Or are you trying to display those in a [ListView widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html), for example?

Comment: If you want, you can edit the question and share your code if it's not too long (otherwise you can share a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) so we can understand your problem better.

Comment: i'm trying to get the value 'Tom Clancy's Without Remorse' from 'title' and assign it to a variable called title1 then i want to get the value called 'Mortal Kombat' and assign it to a variable called title2

Comment: Ok, so after you done `final List<String> titles = (json["results"] as List).map((j) => j["title"]).toList();`, you just need to do `final String title1 = titles[0];` and `final String title2 = titles[1];` If you want to do it in one-shot, you can do `final String title1 = (json["results"] as List).map((j) => j["title"]).toList()[0];`, replacing `[0]` with `[1]` if you want to access the second value, `[2]` the third value and so on.

Comment: it works now!!!!! thank you so much!!!! i been struggling with this for days, thank you for your fast answer and with your help!!

Comment: Really? I'm so happy for you! Is there any errors?

Comment: No errors for now, again, thank you so much for your help!!!